# Criando um gráfico de barras dentro de outro gráfico de barras

Tags: r, histograma

Procuro por um modo bem eficiente e útil de utilizar os gráficos de barras aninhados. 
Um modo em que você possa demonstrar divisões e subdivisões em um mesmo gráfico. Como gerar um gráfico desses em R?

Comment: João, esta pergunta havia sido fechada pois o pessoal achou que não estava claro o que estava sendo perguntado. Nós reabrimos. Entretanto, para tentar evitar este tipo de fechamento, quando for fazer uma pergunta deste tipo, às vezes é interessante colocar um exemplo do que se deseja alcançar (como o próprio gráfico que você colocou na resposta!), ou mais detalhes do que se quer. Segue uma discussão que pode ser útil, Abraços! http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/825#825

Comment: Entendi, Carlos, muito obrigado!Estarei com isto em mente na próxima vez.
Vivendo e aprendendo!

Answer (score 6):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para produzir o gráfico acima basta seguir o exemplo abaixo:

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("reshape")
library(reshape)
install.packages("scales")
library(scales)

#.................
# Exemplo de dados

df <- read.csv(textConnection("Segment,Alpha,Beta,Gamma,Delta
                                 A,1416649,590270,236108,118054
                                 B,708325,531243,354162,177081
                                 C,354162,354162,236108,236108
                                 D,147568,147568,147568,147568"))
closeAllConnections()

#.........................................................
# Colocando tudo em uma mesma escala e rotulando os eixos

dfa <- melt(df, id = c("Segment"), variable_name = "Company")

#...................
# Tratando do eixo Y

ylim <- max(cast(dfa, Company ~ ., sum)[, 2],
            cast(dfa, Segment ~ ., sum)[, 2])

#.........
# Plotando

p <- ggplot(dfa) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,ylim), breaks = NULL)
p1 <- p + geom_bar(aes(Company, value), stat = "identity",breaks = NULL)
(p2 <- p1 + geom_bar(aes(Company, value, fill = Segment),
                     stat = "identity",breaks = NULL, position = "dodge"))
```

Comment: Particularmente, não gosto desse tipo de gráfico. Acho que a mesma informação pode ser visualizada no gráfico de barras empilhadas, que também facilita a comparação da distribuição dos subgrupos entre os grupos.
(http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar-16.png).

Comment: Daniel, é só mais uma alternativa gráfica.
Gosto desta que você apresentou e também desta que coloquei na resposta. 
Dependendo de onde você publicará, jornal, internet, revista, um estilo ou outro pode ser o mais agradável para a interpretação dos leitores.